# parseInt - In Node environment, using radix

Tags: javascript

I was not able to find definite answer, do we still need to use radix (Node)?

```
let number = parseInt('666');
```

VS

```
let number = parseInt('666', 10);
```

Comment: Not specific to Node.js, but MDN states: "Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form MDN to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If *radix* is `undefined` or `0` (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input `string` begins with `"0x"` or `"0X"`, *radix* is `16` (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
> - If the input `string` begins with "0", *radix* is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet. **For this reason always specify a radix when using `parseInt`.**
> - If the input `string` begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

Comment: So best practice is to always use it.